# wp_remote_request to url with port 8001 not woorking

Tags: php, wp-remote-request

I try to send a request with the function **wp_remote_request** and it is not accepted
(Note the port at URL)

When I download the port it is accepted

Where's the problem?

tish is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'body' => array(
            'key' => 'value' 
    )
);
wp_remote_request('http://exemple.com:8001/page', $args);
```

Comment: the request is not accepted by who or what ?

Comment: On the other server side I see that no request was received

Answer (score 0):

I checked the response of the function
And that's the answer:

cURL error 7: Failed connect to website.com:8001; Connection refused

What to do?